# Return DB results from a function in a different file (React Native/Typescript + SQLite)

Tags: typescript, sqlite, react-native

I'm trying to read data in one file from an SQLite database and return it to display in a different file.

Firstly, I'd like to be able to manipulate the data prior to displaying it, for example, return the results into an array I can loop through, run some calculations, then update the rows. Secondly, I'd like to display it in the component, but I can't even seem to do that.

I have a TSX file where I store my CRUD functions. Here's my read one that I want to call from a different file:

```
export const ReadSingleProject = (projectID: string) => {
    SQLite.openDatabase({
    name: "database.db",
    createFromLocation: "~database.db",
    location: "Library",
  }).then((db) => {
    db.transaction((tx) => {
      tx.executeSql(
        "SELECT * FROM projects WHERE projectID=?",
        [projectID],
        (tx, results) => {
          var len = results.rows.length;
          if (len > 0) {          

            return results.rows.raw();

          }
        }
      );
    })
      .catch((error: string) => {
        console.log(error);
      })
      .then(() => {
        db.close().catch((error: string) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
      });
  });
};
```

And then in my component file, I'm simply trying to bring in the results:

```
useEffect(() => {
     let project = ReadSingleProject(projectID); 
  }, []);
```

But this 'project' object comes back saying undefined. I've tried splitting the results into a JSON object in File 1 and returning that to populate a JSON object File 2, but there doesn't appear to be any data, even though when I console log in File 1, the results are there correctly.

Could anyone help, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this by returning a Promise that wrapped the DB results in the function on the 2nd file, then with the returned results on the 1st file, reading them in as typeof SQLite.ResultsSetRowList. Like so:

Component File:

```
    var results: SQLite.ResultSetRowList;
    const response = async (): Promise<any> => {
      await ReadSingleProject(projectID).then((value) => {
        results = value as SQLite.ResultSetRowList; //defined 'undefined' value as ResultSetRowList and populate already defined results variable
        setSingleProject({
          projectName: results.item(0).projectName,
          projectID: results.item(0).projectID,
        });
      });
    };
    response();
```

DB Function File:

```
export function ReadSingleProject(projectID: string) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    SQLite.openDatabase({
      name: "database.db",
      createFromLocation: "~database.db",
      location: "Library",
    }).then((db) =>
      db
        .transaction((tx) => {
          tx.executeSql(
            "SELECT * FROM projects WHERE projectID=?",
            [projectID],
            (tx, results) => {
              var len = results.rows.length;
              if (len > 0) {
                resolve(results.rows); //results wrapped in a promise!
              }
            }
          );
        })
        .catch((error: string) => {
          reject(console.log("Error: " + error));
        })
        .then(() => {
          db.close().catch((error: string) => {
            reject(console.log("Error: " + error));
          });
        })
    );
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **redux** along with **react-redux** which is centralised state management system for React and React Native apps.

For async operations you can use **redux-thunk** using applyMiddleware while creating the store in **App.js** file.

[Getting started with react-redux](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/quick-start)

Comment: Can this only be done with Redux? I'm still learning React/JS you see, and coming from a C# background I'm discovering all sorts of crazy things!

Comment: it is a simple way -  using redux

Answer (score 0):

**use async and await**

the reason you are getting undefined in project because DB operation is asynchronous.

so might want to use async and await for DB operations

```
export const ReadSingleProject = async (projectID: string) => {
    SQLite.openDatabase({
    name: "database.db",
    createFromLocation: "~database.db",
    location: "Library",
  }).then((db) => {
    db.transaction((tx) => {
      tx.executeSql(
        "SELECT * FROM projects WHERE projectID=?",
        [projectID],
        (tx, results) => {
          var len = results.rows.length;
          if (len > 0) {          

            return results.rows.raw();

          }
        }
      );
    })
      .catch((error: string) => {
        console.log(error);
      })
      .then(() => {
        db.close().catch((error: string) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
      });
  });
};
```

then in another file change like this

```
useEffect(() => {
     let project = await ReadSingleProject(projectID); 
  }, []);
```

try changing **then** to **await** and **async** at appropriate places in File 1

Comment: I've just tried asynx/await and I'm getting the same.

Comment: I tried to use it within the function itself, and when calling the function, ie:

const response = async (): Promise<any> => { await ReadSingleProject(projectID);  };
    let results= async function () { response().then((value) => {console.log(value); });};

All I'm getting in console.log is 'undefined'. Do I need to define those results as something? Or can I just populate a blank variable with them? I'm using SQLite, and I'm returning 'results.rows.raw()'... rows uses the interface SQLite.ResultSetRowList, and raw() an interface of just Array<T> Thanks

Comment: Thanks Gogul-S, I've got it working with a mix of asynx/await and defining the returned results correctly so I could read them.